Using spreadsheet named functions in custom functions
Alright, so I'm trying to repeat a function I have made in Google Sheets, called POINTS to calculate a point integer value from a cell parameter -- but sadly, there is no loop function for Sheets so far as I know.
I am now trying to code a function in Apps Script with a loop to run the POINTS function on a range of cells and sum them together; however, I cannot reference the POINTS function or any other named functions available in the actual spreadsheet like SUM or COUNTIF. Does anyone know how to import these functions over or allow the Apps Script to access them?
Here is the code I currently have for the apps script (with the POINTS function where I'd want it if it were possible):
function summing(row, startCol, endCol, function a) {
  
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sum = 0;
  
  for (i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++) {
    sum += POINTS(s.getRange(row, i));
  }
  return sum;
}


You can not call Google Sheets builtin functions from App Script.  Also you should look at Best Practices.  Repeated calls to getRange in a loop is slow and inefficient.

Could you show the POINTS function?

In the same way Google Sheets functions can't be used on Google Apps Script, Google Sheets named functions can't be used either.
It's worth noting that functions declared on Google Apps Script, in the Google Sheets context, are not "custom functions". While it's not mandatory, a custom function should contain JSDocs with the @customformula tag. Reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions.
Instead of creating a Google Sheets custom function, could you make a named function that does what you need? Not too long ago, Google added a large set of Google Sheets functions. For details, see

Adding more flexibility to functions in Sheets
Google Sheets adds powerful new functions for advanced analysis

Another option is to write a JavaScript code to do what the POINTS named function does.
